# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{4i^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 \times (2n+1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How could we show $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4i^2-1}=\frac{n}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 \times (2n+1)}$$ I am looking for an answer other than induction as in the actual problem I am suppose to find out a representation of the sum (I used [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1/%284%20i%5E2%20-%201%29,%20%7Bi,%201,%20n%7D%5D) to get that representation).Experimenting with smaller sums it is not much difficult to identify the form $\frac{n}{2n+1}$ however, I would appreciate if anybody show me other methods to obtain those forms.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309300/complete-induction-sumn-i-1-frac12i-12i1-fracn2n1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sum can be computed using telescoping: $\frac1{4n^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)$, so in the sum all terms but $\frac12\cdot 1$ and $-\frac12\cdot\frac1{2n+1}$ cancel.

Comment: Ehhh I was very close to this solution.Thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 6):

It may be worth trying
$$
\frac{1}{{4n^2  - 1}} = \frac{1}{{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)}} = \frac{1}{{2(2n - 1)}} - \frac{1}{{2(2n + 1)}}
$$
and considering telescoping series.